# PyGobject Error: gtk_grid_attach_next_to: assertion 'sibling == NULL || gtk_widget_get_parent (sibling) == (GtkWidget*)grid' failed

Tags: python, user-interface, gtk

I have created an alignment container and instead of creating 1000 alignment containers to align half my widgets to the right side of the program, I tried attaching the widgets below the first aligned widget. However, this gives me the error:

> gtk_grid_attach_next_to: assertion 'sibling == NULL ||
>   gtk_widget_get_parent (sibling) == (GtkWidget*)grid' failed

The only solution I can find is to make 1000 alignment containers. I tried using `grid.add` and placing in the right spot, however that doesn't work. I also tried attaching the widget under the alignment container which doesn't put it in the correct spot. Here is the code for the widgets I am trying to align to the right.

```
self.CurrentPopulationLabel = Gtk.Label("Current Population: " + `self.CurrentPopulation`)
self.MaximumPopulationLabel = Gtk.Label("Maximum Population: " + `self.MaximumPopulation`)

align1 = Gtk.Alignment()
align1.set_padding(0,0,1000,0)
align1.add(self.CurrentPopulationLabel)
grid.attach_next_to(align1, self.PerSecondLabel1, Gtk.PositionType.RIGHT, 1, 1)
grid.attach_next_to(self.MaximumPopulationLabel, self.CurrentPopulationLabel, Gtk.PositionType.BOTTOM, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are trying to attach a widget next to another widget that wasn't already attached in the grid, so the second to last line will throw an error.  Saying that, I do not understand what you are trying to do and you are rather vague in your example.

Comment: It's in the grid indirectly, the container which holds it is in the grid. However, the widget itself is nested in that container.